# Public IP address vs Private IP address

Tags: networking, web-applications, ip-address

Good day to all,

I am trying to study networking basics. Watched a ton of videos, researched abit and understood better. However I can't find answers to what I am curious about. Forgive me, I am just a beginner in this IT thing.

A computer has a Public IP address (which is sensitive), and obtains a Private IP address after it is connected to a router.

A router has a Public IP address and also a Private IP address (192.168.1.1 for linksys). It will then assign all the devices connnected to it which its own Private IP address, for example 192.168.1.102.

So here is something I don't quite understand (even after researching online);

1. Mobile phones uses its own public ip address to connect to the internet via Mobile Data, is that right?
2. Desktop does not uses its public address at all since it is always connected to a router which assigns it a private ip address?
3. When a computer outside the network wants to connect to a computer inside a network, does the connection happen directly between computer to computer or does it have to connect through the router where the router will then pass the connection to the computer inside the network?

I can't seem to find any explanation how computer IP public address are utilised since it is always connected to a router where it has its own private IP address.

Forgive me, I am just a beginner. Thank you in advance.

Comment: First, understand that IP does not have a difference between public or private addresses. IANA, the IETF, and the ISPs have simply chosen some IP blocks to not route on the public internet, and those are called private addresses. IP knows nothing about that. Also, many companies own blocks of public addresses that get advertised and routed from the company network to the public internet.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Yes(Mobile Phones are connected via radio masts which are provided by your provider.)

2.) Yes, Desktop Computers same as Mobile Phones which are connected to the router via wifi use the routers IP Adress.

3.) If a computer outside the networks needs data from a computer inside your network it sends a request to your router which forwards it to your computer (which request are forwarded determines the firewall of your router). Also if you request data from a computer outside your network you send a request to your router and the router sends a request to the network of the other computer.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that a desktop’s public ip address will never be used to communicate with any other devices outside a network map? Since it does not communicate directly, and it uses router to communicate.

Comment: There is no public IP inside a network just private IPs like 10.0.0.x or 192.168.xxx.xxx. These are there to identify computer inside the network. The public IP as you discribe is the IP of the router.

Comment: Oh there is no public IP for a computer inside a network? Cause when I did a search on my ip it gave me two different IP; 192.168.xxx.xxx and 67.142.xxx.xxx.

Comment: Yeah it is "public" for the inside of the network but public in most cases means that you can't access exactly this computer from the outside of the network.